# How to use expression with '<' and '>' in CakePHP Model

Tags: cakephp

How to generate this statement correctly from CakePHP?

```
DELETE FROM table as Table WHERE Table.expire < NOW();
```

I have tried this but this is not working:

```
$this->deleteAll(array(
    'Table.expire <' => $this->getDataSource()->expression('NOW()')
));

//It complains:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Table.expire <' in 'where clause'

SQL Query: 
SELECT `Table`.`id` FROM `database`.`table` AS `Table`   WHERE `Table.expire <` = NOW()
```

The only way to make it working now is by making the whole condition as a string:

```
$this->deleteAll('Table.expire < NOW()');
:: OR ::
$this->deleteAll(array('Table.expire < NOW()'));
```

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with using $this->deleteAll(array('Table.expire < NOW()')) if that's working for you and creating the correct SQL. Conditions do not need to always be "index => value" form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested your situation, because I was a bit surprised that CakePHP didn't properly 'quote'

```
Table.expire <
```

to

```
`Table`.`expire` <
```

(which it normally does).

This *may* be related to the fact that `$this->getDataSource()->expression('NOW()')` Returns a `stdObject` with 'NOW()' as a 'value' property. Maybe this is a 'special' case in the logic of CakePHP, I'm not really sure.

### Array-notation assumes 'literal' values, not 'expressions'

Anyway, *in general*, the 'array notation' will regard the value passed a 'literal' value, not an expression, and therefore quote it as such, e.g.

```
'conditions' => array('Table.expire <' => 'some value')
'conditions' => array('Table.expire < ?' => 'another value')
'conditions' => array('Table.expire <' => 'NOW()')
```

Will all be regarded 'literal' values, resulting in these SQL conditions;

```
WHERE `Table`.`expire` < 'some value'
WHERE `Table`.`expire` < 'another value'
WHERE `Table`.`expire` < 'NOW()'
```

The values are thus regarded a *string* and 'NOW()' will not be seen as 'the current date/time' by the database.

### Options

This will leave you with some options;

### Specify the condition as a String, not a key/value array

You already provided this option in your question:

```
'conditions' => array('Table.expire < NOW()')
```

This solution should be safe in your situation (no user input is included in the statement), however, *if* user input will be included in such statement, it should be properly sanitized. Also, `NOW()` may not be valid cross-database (ANSI SQL uses `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for the current date/time)

### Specify the current date/time as a ISO-date, not as an 'expression'

This is the alproach I normally use;
If you prefer the array-notation, you may consider to provide a 'literal' date for the condition, preferably as an ISO-date, which is handled properly by most databases;

```
'conditions' => array('Table.expire <' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))

// or

'conditions' => array('Table.expire < ?' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
```

**note** I've created all my examples to be used as the 'conditions' key for a `find()`, however, the same will apply for a `deleteAll()`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ah thanks for the input. I think the best is to just provide it as a String literal for now as it's relatively safe (no SQL injection), and we do not have any plan to migrate the database system in the near future. And the correct datetime format should be `Y-m-d H:i:s` ;)

Comment: Glad I could assist. You're right on the format, overlooked that while writing it down. I modified my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$this->delete("all", array('conditions'=>array(
    'Table.expire < ' => $this->getDataSource()->expression('NOW()')))
    );
```

Comment: It doesn't delete the records at all